# C++ std::set With Custom Class Returning Wrong lower_bound Value

Tags: c++, set, std, lower-bound

In the code below, there is class `Tile`, and `TQ`, a set of `Tile`s, of which i use the struct `tCmp_id` to compare the set elements. `mkTile` simply returns a `Tile` object given an id value.
In main, i add four elements to `TQ`: 4 tiles, with ids of 1, 2, 4, and 5.

I also call `upper_bound` and `lower_bound` on `TQ`, which should give 2 and 4, respectively. However, on I running the program, I'm getting 4 and 4, respectively, as outputs.
Here's the code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <set>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class Tile {
    public:
        int id;
};
struct tCmp_id {
    bool operator()(Tile a, Tile b) const {
        return a.id < b.id;
    }
};

set<Tile, tCmp_id> TQ;

Tile mkTile(int id){
    Tile t;
    t.id = id;
    return t;
}

int main(){
    TQ.insert(mkTile(1));
    TQ.insert(mkTile(2));
    TQ.insert(mkTile(4));
    TQ.insert(mkTile(5));

    cout << (*TQ.lower_bound(mkTile(3))).id << endl;
    cout << (*TQ.upper_bound(mkTile(3))).id << endl;
}
```

Can somebody explain what's going on here? I've tried searching online or editing `tCmp_id`, but nothing's working so far. Thanks in advance

Comment: you misunderstand upper and lower bound. You get the same behavior with a simple `set<int>`

Comment: @pm100 Got it now. I recently switched from Java to CPP a few weeks ago, so just starting to get used to it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`std::set::lower_bound` - Returns an iterator pointing to the first element that is not less than (i.e. greater or equal to) key.

`std::set::upper_bound` - Returns an iterator pointing to the first element that is greater than key.

Since you use `3` as the key to search for, you'll get `4` in both cases.

For `lower_bound` `4` is the first value not less than 3, i.e. it's greater or equal to `3`.

For `upper_bound` `4` is the first value greater than `3`.